# C# WinForms - Chart draws more points that specified

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm writing a simple WinForm app that is supposed to draw graphs based on input edges.

In an example, where I enter 5 edges (labeled: 0,1,2,3,4) Chart draws 8 additional points for every edge, that go like a line. I'm suspecting that WinForm is trying to do some graph normalization which creates additional points based on the existing ones, but I can't find the option which causes this.

[image: Only Points labeled are the ones that I entered, the rest of them is coming from I don't know where]

Code that draws the Points:

```
foreach (int pt in points)
                    {

                        double dx = pointsToDraw[pt].X;
                        double dy = pointsToDraw[pt].Y;
                        chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(dx, dy);
                        chart1.Series[0].Points[pt].Label = pt.ToString();

                    }
```

points array in foreach statement:

```
[0] 0   int
[1] 1   int
[2] 2   int
[3] 3   int
[4] 4   int
```

pointsToDraw list, with all the Points with attached coordinates:

```
+       [0] {X = 260 Y = 385}   System.Drawing.Point
+       [1] {X = 320 Y = 385}   System.Drawing.Point
+       [2] {X = 240 Y = 385}   System.Drawing.Point
+       [3] {X = 250 Y = 370}   System.Drawing.Point
+       [4] {X = 400 Y = 370}   System.Drawing.Point
```

EDIT:

It's weird, becuase chart1_Paint method executes infinetely, and this is why there are so many points. Here's the method:

```
private void chart1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            List<Point> pointsToDraw = new List<Point>();
            List<int> pointsList = new List<int>();
            int[] points;

            if (Tree != null)
            {
               foreach(Tuple<int,int> tp in Tree)
                {
                    pointsList.Add(tp.Item1);
                    pointsList.Add(tp.Item2);
                }
                IEnumerable<int> pointsDistinct = pointsList.Distinct();
                pointsDistinct = pointsDistinct.OrderBy(s => s);
                points = pointsDistinct.ToArray();

                for (int i = 0; i < points.Count(); i++)
                {
                    Point pt = new Point(begX, begY);
                    pointsToDraw.Add(pt);
                }
                int y = 1;
                List<int> pointsAdded = new List<int>();
                for (int i = 0; i < points.Count(); i++)
                {
                    foreach (Tuple<int, int> tp in Tree)
                    {

                        if(points[i] == tp.Item1)
                        {
                            if(pointsAdded.Where(x => x == points[i]).Count() == 0)
                            {
                                pointsToDraw[tp.Item1] = new Point(begX, begY);
                                begX = begX + 10;
                                begY = begY - 15;
                                pointsAdded.Add(points[i]);
                            }
                            if (pointsAdded.Where(x => x == tp.Item2).Count() == 0)
                            {

                                pointsToDraw[tp.Item2] = new Point(pointsToDraw[tp.Item1].X+(10*y), pointsToDraw[tp.Item1].Y-15);

                                pointsAdded.Add(tp.Item2);
                            }
                        }
                        if (points[i] == tp.Item2)
                        {
                            if (pointsAdded.Where(x => x == points[i]).Count() == 0)
                            {
                                pointsToDraw[tp.Item2] = new Point(begX, begY);
                                begX = begX - 10;
                                begY = begY - 15;
                                pointsAdded.Add(points[i]);
                            }
                            if (pointsAdded.Where(x => x == tp.Item1).Count() == 0)
                            {
                                pointsToDraw[tp.Item2] = new Point(pointsToDraw[tp.Item1].X + (10 * y), pointsToDraw[tp.Item1].Y - 15);

                                pointsAdded.Add(tp.Item2);
                            }
                        }
                        y++;
                    }
                }

                    foreach (int pt in points)
                    {

                    double dx = pointsToDraw[pt].X;//chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(pointsToDraw[pt].X);
                        double dy = pointsToDraw[pt].Y;//chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.PixelPositionToValue(pointsToDraw[pt].Y);
                        chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(dx, dy);
                        chart1.Series[0].Points[pt].Label = pt.ToString();

                    }
                if (pointsToDraw.Count > 1)
                    using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2.5f))
                        foreach (Tuple<int, int> tp in Tree)
                        {
                            Point[] eds = new Point[] { pointsToDraw[tp.Item1], pointsToDraw[tp.Item2] };
                            e.Graphics.DrawLines(pen, eds);
                        }
            }

            }
```

I run it by clicking a button and executing chart1.Invalidate() method.

Comment: WinForms won't be doing anything that you don't tell it to do. What chart control/library are you using?

Comment: System.Drawing;
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

As for the chart, I'm using the standard "Chart" from WinForm toolbox

Comment: This obviously is a MSChart and just as obviously it will do nothing like that. You must have some more code.. Note that the other loops do not add the Labels!

Comment: Yes, looks like chart1_Paint method is executing in loop for some reason. I posted more detail in the original question

Comment: What's the reason for rendering the chart in its paint handler?  If you need to custom draw it has more specific paint related events.  Hard to see why you would do non-custom work like adding points in any of those events.

Comment: __You don't draw Points in a chart__ you only sometimes want to adorn the chart. And of course you don't add any points there!! The Paint events are called whenever the system deems it necessary..So you don't have control over it!

Comment: To make it even clearer (?): Whenever you add a DataPoint the chart must redraw itself. To do so it eventually will call the Paint event(s). The system may cache/queue some, but, yes this is an almost classic endless loop..

Comment: Yep, looks like doing all those Points maniuplation inside Paint method was reallu dumb idea. I moved all of that logic to onClick method, and now it works correctly.

Thanks for all the help!